# CRUDRepository::delete executes silently while the execution should violate FK and throw an exception

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Good afternoon,

Using Spring Boot + JPA + Hibernate, I am expecting an exception while trying to delete an entity still being referenced by another entity (violation of my FK constraint). I am using a CRUDRepository and I was expecting to be able to catch a DataIntegrityViolationException out of the delete or deleteById call.

However, nothing happens and the logs only show a select query:

```
Hibernate: select jpauserpas0_.id as id1_4_0_, jpauserpas0_.cdate as cdate2_4_0_, jpauserpas0_.password as password3_4_0_, jpauser1_.id as id1_3_1_, jpauser1_.cdate as cdate2_3_1_, jpauser1_.pid as pid4_3_1_, jpauser1_.username as username3_3_1_ from user_password jpauserpas0_ left outer join "user" jpauser1_ on jpauserpas0_.id=jpauser1_.pid where jpauserpas0_.id=?
```

**Will someone have an idea why this is happening? Is this a normal behaviour?**

Model:

```
public class JPAUser
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "genuser", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "genuser", sequenceName = "user_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    public Integer id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    public String username;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pid")
    public JPAUserPassword password;

    public JPAUser(String username, JPAUserPassword password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    ...
}

public class JPAUserPassword
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "genupwd", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "genupwd", sequenceName = "upwd_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    public Integer id;

    @Column(nullable=false, updatable=false)
    public String value;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "password")
    public JPAUser user;

    public JPAUserPassword(String value)
    {
        this.password = value;
    }
    ...
}
```

Code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan("model.package.name")
@EnableJpaRepositories("repository.package.name")
public class JPATestConfiguration
{
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }
}

@Repository
public interface JPAUserRepository extends CrudRepository<JPAUser, Integer>
{
}

@Repository
public interface JPAUserPasswordRepository extends CrudRepository<JPAUserPassword, Integer>
{
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:/application-test.properties")
@SpringBootTest(classes={JPATestConfiguration.class})
public class JPAUserPasswordTest
{
    @Autowired
    private JPAUserPasswordRepository userPasswordRepository;

    @Autowired
    private JPAUserRepository userRepository;

    private final String USERNAME = "username";
    private final String PASSWORD = "password";

    @Test
    public void deleteAttachedEntity()
    {
        JPAUserPassword jpaUserPassword = new JPAUserPassword(PASSWORD);
        JPAUser jpaUser = new JPAUser(USERNAME, jpaUserPassword);

        userRepository.save(jpaUser);

        int id = jpaUserPassword.getId();

        // any of the two should throw the exception
        userPasswordRepository.delete(jpaUserPassword);
        userPasswordRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

application-test.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/MYDB?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Dependencies:

- Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE
- Postgresql 42.2.5
- Hibernate Core 5.3.7.Final

Comment: remove cascade.ALL and it will work...

Comment: Agreed with that but I still want to be able to cascade delete the user so this doesn't work for me. And it still doesn't tell me why trying to delete the foreign entity directly doesn't trigger an integrity violation.

Answer (score 0):

```
// any of the two should throw the exception
userPasswordRepository.delete(jpaUserPassword);
userPasswordRepository.deleteById(id);

Above will delete record from child entity JPA`enter code here`UserPassword, so constraint violation error won't come.

If constraint violation is required on JPAUser, then remove CascadeType.ALL or make it CascadeType.PERSIST
```

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to me. I may still want to enjoy the benefits of the cascade policy on a parent-child relationship while being aware of constraint violations if interacting with the child directly.